# Trying to write a vuepress plugin

Tags: plugins, vuepress

(The doc on writing a plugin is pretty sparse...)

**THE GOAL**

Create a plugin to add headers to a page.

**THE ATTEMPT**

Created a plugin following guidelines and an example plugin (that presumably works...) to do something similar.

**THE ISSUE**

Plugin won't load.

**config.js**

```
  plugins: [
    [
    'vuepress-plugin-headertags',
    { headerTags: ["<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/netlify-identity-widget@1.5.2/build/netlify-identity-widget.min.js'></script>"]}
    ]
  ],
```

(the <script> tag is what I'm trying to insert, in this instance.

**PLUGIN index.js**

```
const { path } = require('path')
// was:  const { path } = require('@vuepress/shared-utils')
// dunno.  No documentation on this...
// got the current version from the 'default-theme' code

module.exports = (options) => ({
  define () {
    return {
      headerTags: options.headerTags || []
    }
  },
  enhanceAppFiles () {
    return [path.resolve(__dirname, 'enhanceAppFile.js')]
  },
  globalUIComponents: ['HeaderTags']
})
```

**PLUGIN INSTALLATION**
I published it to npm as `vuepress-plugin-headertags`, and then installed it with:

`yarn add -D vuepress-plugin-headertags`

Here's the relevant package.json content:

```
{
  "name": "vuepress-netlifycms",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vuepress dev",
    "build": "vuepress build",
    "debug": "node --nolazy --inspect=9229 /home/rickb/.yarn/bin/vuepress build"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "vuepress": "^0.14.8",
    "vuepress-plugin-headertags": "^1.0.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

**VUEPRESS INSTALLATION**

I cloned the vuepress repo from git and did a yarn link, which makes it globally available.  With that, I can trace it in the debugger via the 'debug' script.

**TRACING**

I've followed the VP source code in the debugger and get to `resolvePathPackage()` in `moduleResolver.js`.  The incoming path is not correct:

`/home/(...)/VuePress-NetlifyCMS/vuepress-plugin-headertags`

It should be:

`/home/(...)/VuePress-NetlifyCMS/node_modules/vuepress-plugin-headertags`

At any rate, it doesn't resolve, even after the 'normalization' process.

**MORE EYES**

I need more eyes on this to help me figure it out.  The project is already up on github as 'rickbsgu/VuePress-NetlifyCMS.git'.  If you do an install, the plugin will be in the project directory under 'node_modules/vuepress-plugin-headertags'

Any thoughts appreciated

Comment: You know that you can config [head](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/config/#head) in VuePress, right? And I suggest you upgrade VuePress to the latest version `1.4.0`, I got an error after the upgrade which leads me to the bug: `const path = require('path')`. I'm not sure this needs to be [documented](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path) in VuePress.

Comment: Hah!  No, I did not see that.  Of course, it still needs to load.  I am using version 1.4.0, pulled straight from the github repo.  So, if you got the error, that suggests it's loading for you, which is further than I'm getting.  Thanx.

Comment: Have to think about why it would load for you and not for me.  Maybe something not quite right in my environment?  Using the 'head' directive would reduce the plugin to a single file entity, which would certainly be simpler.  I would, however, like to see the full implementation work, just for future reference.

Comment: Oops - I had a vuepress in my package.json, wrong version.  Wasn't getting my freshly pulled version.  Think that's the issue.

Answer (score 1):

And it works, now.  Two problems:

- Version I was running/debugging was not the same as the version in package.json.  There is the vuepress executable *and* the vuepress libraries the plugin requires.  The library was always the older version at runtime.
- I needed to change the path import in index.html from `const { path } = require('path')` to `const { path } = require('@vuepress/shared-utils').`  That's my doc issue - I don't see that documented anywhere.

Thanks [@Sun Haoran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9478849/sun-haoran) for getting me to look in the right place.